# Proof of sum rule of differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to prove the sum rule of differentiation, but stuck on a particular step. Given a function $f(x) = u(x) + v(x)$, we try to differentiate $f$ using the definition of derivatives:

$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{df}{dx} &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\\
                  &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x + h) + v(x + h) - u(x) - v(x)}{h}\\
                  &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x+h) -u(x) + v(x+h) - v(x)}{h}\\
                  &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \Big(\frac{u(x+h) -u(x)}{h} + \frac{v(x+h) - v(x)}{h}\Big)\\
                  &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x+h) -u(x)}{h} + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{v(x+h) - v(x)}{h}\\
\end{align}
$$

This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to justify this last move, the distribution of the limit operator over the sum.

**References**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum rule for differentiation assumes first that both $u'(x)$ and $v'(x)$ exist, so the limits exist
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h}\\
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h},
\end{align*}
now turns the basic rule for limits allows us to deduce the existence of 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\dfrac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h}+\dfrac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}\right)
\end{align*}
which the value is 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h}+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's helpful, but I still don't see how the last formula follows from the one before.

Comment: So essentially you have question on the reason why $\lim(f(x)+g(x))=\lim f(x)+\lim g(x)$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my question. Sorry wasn't clear.

Comment: One needs to assume that both $\lim f(x)=M$ and $\lim g(x)=L$ exist first, then one uses $\epsilon$-argument to deduce that $|f(x)+g(x)-(M+L)|=|(f(x)-M)+(g(x)-L)|\leq|f(x)-M|+|g(x)-L|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$ to complete showing that $\lim(f(x)+g(x))=M+L$.